# Cann't use transaction statements in JS

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm trying to use the code below to get the data in MYSQL, but using BEGIN and COMMIT Statements will cause an error.

I try to delete BEGIN, COMMIT and delete only one statement. The program can work.

```
    let sql = `BEGIN; 
                INSERT INTO info(ID, Nametitle, Firstname, Lastname, Date, Jobtitle, Telephone, Picname)
                VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
                SELECT @last := LAST_INSERT_ID();
                INSERT INTO user_accounts(userID, username, password, userID) 
                VALUES(NUll ,?, ?, @last);
               COMMIT;`;
```

> sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
> use near 'INSERT INTO info(ID, Nametitle, Firstname, Lastname,
> Date, Jobtitle, Tel' at line 2",

Comment: JavaScript is irrelevant here. Which library are you using to interact with the database?

Comment: @VLAZ I use Express

Answer (score 0):

Use START TRANSACTION rather than BEGIN.

Additionally it looks like you're using node-mysql to enable multiple statements. That is highly discouraged because it leads to security problems and sql injection...